# Como criar diretório com um caminho que funcione para qualquer SO?

Tags: java, diretório, path

Estou fazendo um trabalho em Java e preciso que meu programa crie um diretório na pasta "home" do usuário, porém ele precisa ser capaz de criar tanto em Linux quanto em Windows. É possível criar um caminho "genérico" para tal?

Comment: O uso do diretório é para que? Nesse caso haveria a possibilidade de criação de um pacote em Java e assim armazenar os arquivos?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para pegar o "home" do usuário basta usar:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

Para a criação e uso de diretórios não importa a plataforma você faz do mesmo jeito:

```
File arquivo = new File("/dir/arquivo.ext");
Path dir = Paths.get("/dir/sub");
```

Mesmo no Windows você pode usar desta forma, a API se encarregará de resolver.

Provavelmente você vai querer fazer algo assim:

```
boolean ok = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "seudir").mkdirs();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/CreateDir.java).

[Documentação do `mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()).

Você pode preferir usar `mkdir()` em outros casos. A diferença para o `mkdirs()` é que o primeiro não cria nada em diretórios não existentes.  O segundo provavelmente não fará diferença porque acabou recebeu o *path* do sistema. Embora improvável é possível existir uma [*race condition*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) e logo em seguida a pegar o `user.home` ele deixar de existir, com o `mkdir()` falhará, com o `mkdirs()` ele será criado novamente. Você escolhe o que prefere em uma situação extrema assim.