# Problema com caminhos em JAVA

Tags: java, javafx, path

Estou em um projeto e me encontro com o seguinte problema.

uma parte do código tem o seguinte:

```
  Path caminho2 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Evandro\\Documents\\Java\\Player beta 0.9\\src\\Capas\\Gifs".replace("\\", "/"));
        List<Path> listaCapas2;
        System.out.println(listaImagem2.size());
        try {
            listaCapas2 = Files.list(caminho2).collect(Collectors.toList());
            listaCapas2.forEach((capas2) -> {
                listaImagem2.add(new Image(capas2.toFile().toURI().toString()));
            });
            addItem2(listaImagem2);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

preciso que esse "path" seja para todos os computadores, e não apenas para o meu.

> "Path caminho2 =
>   Paths.get("C:\Users\Evandro\Documents\Java\Player beta
>   0.9\src\Capas\Gifs".replace("\", "/"));"

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir");` retorna o diretório de trabalho do usuário, independente da maquina.

Comment: porem ao usar isso, ;
          String caminhoo = pastaGeral + "\\Documents\\Java\\Player beta 0.9\\src\\Capas\\Gifs"; o meu projeto teria que ficar nos documentos do outro computador. Eu quero que o caminho seja automático, independentemente da pasta onde o projeto se encontra.

Comment: Então faça uma rotina para criar um novo diretório dentro do retornado por `System.getProperty("user.dir");`. Pois todo sistema operacional tem uma pasta de usuário.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42701/como-criar-diret%C3%B3rio-com-um-caminho-que-funcione-para-qualquer-so

Comment: Essa pasta está dentro do projeto java ou é um recurso externo?